# dynamic programming, nth string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How to solve the   problem https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/special-numbers-39d71325/.

The first number in a sequence of numbers is 1. Every subsequent ith number of the sequence is constructed by applying the following operations on the (i-1)th number:

- Replacing 1 with 114
- Replacing 4 with 1

Therefore, the sequence will be as follows:

1, 114, 1141141, 11411411141141114 , ...

Write a program to find a digit which is the jth  digit of the ith number in this sequence. If the ith number has less than j digits, print -1.

**Input format**

- First line: T (number of test cases)
- First line in each test case: Two space-separated integers i and j

**Output format**

For each test case, print a digit which is the jth digit of the ith number in this sequence. If the ith number has less than j digits, print -1.

**Constraints**

1<=T<=10000(10 to the power 4)

1<=i<=1000000(10 to the power 6)

1<=j<=1000000000000(10 to the power 12)

---

```
Sample input                            Sample output
4
2 2                                               1
2 3                                               4
3 6                                               4
3 7                                               1
```

---

**Explanation**

1st test case: 2nd number in the sequence is 114,     2nd digit is 1.

2nd test case: 2nd number in the sequence is 114,     3rd digit is 4.

3rd test case: 3rd number in the sequence is 1141141, 6th digit is 4.

4th test case: 3rd number in the sequence is 1141141, 7th(last) digit is 1.

---

Storing all the strings (upto ith string) in vector will take enormous amount of time. The tag of the problem is memoization(dynamic programming). I want code/strategy  using memoization(dynamic programming).

---

I don't think the following approach of mine is even closer to what the actual/correct solution will be.

---

See the comment after the line    `vector<string> v(15);`

---

**If this is wrong platform to ask such questions, tell me where to ask such questions.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
#include<climits>
//#define tr(v,it) for(typeof(v.begin()) it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v(15);//v(14) runs under 1 sec even v(15) gives tle. So think how much time v(1000000) will take.
    v[0]="1";
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    int n,h,i,j,tc;
    string s,s1;


    char ch='a';
    for(it=v.begin()+1;it!=v.end();it++) {//set value
         s=*(it-1); s1="";
         for(unsigned int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
             char ch=s[i];
             if(ch=='1') {
                 s1=s1+"114";
             }
             else {
                 s1=s1+'1';
             }
         }
         *it=s1;
    }
    /*for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++) {//print value
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
    cin>>tc;
    while(tc--) {
        cin>>i>>j;
        cout<<v[i-1][j-1];

    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

//Thanks and regards

Comment: Links die over time. State the problem here, not your third party link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now the question is complete. I have stated the whole problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the sequence and its length;

```
114
3
114 114 1
7
114 114 1 114 114 1 114
    7         7      3
   773       773     7
773 773 7 773 773 7 773
...
```

Each length is a doubling of the previous sequence concatenated with the sequence before that, AKA:

```
length(i) =
  2 * length(i - 1) + length(i - 2)
```

Given a position in the final string, since we know the previous sequence lengths, we can determine of it's in (1) the first of the doubled previous, (2) the second of the doubled previous, or (3) the appended, second to last sequence.

By tracking it's location, we keep transforming its position to one that's in one of the previous sequences, until we get to the very first.

For example:

```
    7         7      3
114 114 1 114 114 1 114
                  ^
```

We know the previous two sequences were of length 7 and 3, so we can determine that we are on the 7th index of the second 7-length sequence. Now we continue:

```
114 114 1
        ^
```

The previous two sequence lengths were 3 and 1 so we are on the 1st index of the second to last sequence (the one with length 1).

Result: 1

Comment: It seems you need to have an array of lengths potentially size of 10^6 as per your algorithm, because you need them to track back to find the right position?

Comment: @SomeDude it would seem so.

Comment: Ok. I cannot think of more efficient approach either unless more space of the order of 10^12 can be consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer by גלעד ברקן, here is the Java code :

```
private static void getDigit( int n, long k ) {
    long[] L = new long[n+1];
    L[1] = 1;
    L[2] = 3;
    long MAX = Long.parseUnsignedLong("1000000000000");
    for ( int i = 3; i <= n; i++ ) {
      L[i] = 2*L[i-1] + L[i-2];
      if ( L[i] >= MAX ) break;
    }

    Long k1 = Long.valueOf(k);
    String s = "114";
    while ( n > 2 ) {
      if ( k1 <= L[n-1] ) {
          n--;
      } else if ( k1 > L[n-1] && k1 <= 2*L[n-1] ) {
        k1 = k1 - L[n-1];
        n--;
      } else {
        k1 = k1 - 2*L[n-1];
        n = n - 2;
      }
    }
    System.out.println( String.valueOf( s.charAt(k1.intValue()-1)));
}
```

You can test it [here](https://repl.it/repls/CelebratedAffectionateDirectory) by passing different n, k values.